# Prevent from entering controller in ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here is an excerpt from my $stateProvider configuration

```
  .state('main', {
    url: '/',
    auth: true,
    views: {
      '@': {
        templateUrl: 'main.html',
        controller: 'MainController'
      },
      'content@main' : {}
    },
    resolve: {
      $user: function ($q, Session) {
        return Session.user();
      }
    },
    onEnter: function($state, Session, $timeout) {
      $timeout(function() { 
        var role = Session.checkUserRole();
        if (role !== 'administrator') {
          $state.go('redirect');
        }
      }, 0);
    }
  })
```

What happens is that even if the role is not 'administrator', it still executes all the codes that are in MainController. Previously, I have the logic in my $stateChangeStart but Session.checkUserRole() is always returning null after I just finished signing in. This is most likely due to the nature of Javascript being asynchronous. And yes, it is true that the commands in my run.js finishes first before the promise in the Auth function I called. :(

I was searching if resolve can be written differently to accomodate what I want to happen.

I also didn't like the idea of putting $state.go inside MainController because you will still be able to see the application though only for like 500ms. Still very bad! And even if I get redirected to the warning page, I still see my app made calls to the backend and was able to retrieve data.

If Session.checkUserRole() was returning the correct value and not null inside my .run, I would have been done

Any thoughts/ideas?

Comment: You should look at the documentation for the state change events that get broadcasted on the `$rootScope`.  You can run code before the state successfully changes and cancel the event if the user doesn't have the right permissions.

Comment: Yup, I'm currently using $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams) { as well as $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, I'll check the documentation again regarding cancelling an event

Comment: My code previously inside $stateChangeStart is if (Session.isAuthenticated() && Session.checkUserRole() !== 'administrator') { event.preventDefault(); $state.go('redirect'); } However, Session.checkUserRole() was returning null. The culprit is think is the second REST api call that grabs the user type. This is from our Session factory.

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed finally after converting the function in Session factory into a promise then using that promise in stateProvider. :)